# Exclude different columns in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a loop where in every loop I want to exclude certain columns from `data`.  For example, first loop just excludes x, second loop excludes x & y, third loop excludes x & y & z.  Is this something possible / what is the simplest solution?

```
for c in ["x","x"&"y","x"&"y"&"z"]:
    print(data.loc[:, data.columns != c])
```

data:

```
        y     c1372     c5244  ...            x         y     z
1   0.028292 -0.058234 -0.037606  ...         0         0   205.6
2   0.165635  0.256138  0.151508  ...         0         0   211.5
3   0.183923  0.171580  0.175374  ...         1         0   249.6
4   0.022088 -0.013564 -0.101703  ...         0         1   300.0
5  -0.151817  0.075051  0.159244  ...         0         0   306.7
6   0.339450  0.213238  0.241306  ...         0         0   263.5
7   0.157235  0.178404  0.255837  ...         1         0   370.0
8  -0.024312 -0.023970  0.009638  ...         0         1   433.0
9   0.002836 -0.024721  0.021513  ...         0         0   422.6
10  0.181220  0.155019  0.274975  ...         0         0   423.8
11  0.149472  0.094751  0.194383  ...         1         0   508.0
12 -0.038536 -0.095078 -0.051442  ...         0         1   589.9
13 -0.024252 -0.058521 -0.013778  ...         0         0   567.6
14  0.148980  0.178733  0.188664  ...         0         0   554.0
15  0.103337  0.095121  0.158011  ...         1         0   643.0
16  0.027118  0.021383  0.011049  ...         0         1   713.0
17  0.003271 -0.009936  0.033870  ...         0         0   732.6
18  0.106625  0.160375  0.167086  ...         0         0   735.0
19  0.093675  0.008717  0.052582  ...         1         0   817.7
20 -0.020589  0.002763  0.035459  ...         0         1   898.0
21 -0.014196 -0.028694  0.011052  ...         0         0   879.7
22  0.272170  0.348475  0.254698  ...         0         0   867.3
23  0.089336  0.040760  0.068140  ...         1         0  1138.6
24 -0.019957 -0.023532 -0.021013  ...         0         1  1245.0
25 -0.004846 -0.023470  0.014300  ...         0         0  1220.4
26  0.125502  0.069990  0.067689  ...         0         0  1214.5
27  0.087163  0.027069  0.036068  ...         1         0  1376.9
28 -0.029246  0.008492  0.005794  ...         0         1  1502.3
29 -0.012622 -0.025764 -0.021671  ...         0         0  1459.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
for c in [["x"],["x","y"],["x","y","z"]]:
    print(data.drop(c,axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your approach but with data.columns != c instead of drop, and it didn't work - any idea why?

Comment: @ZJAY you can check the website to see how the drop work https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this:

```
my_loops_cols = ["x", "y", "z"]
for i in range(1, len(my_loops_cols) + 1):
    exclude_cols = my_loops_cols[:i]
    # code to exlude the columns
```